# Generalising found transformation matrix to a whole image

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, affinetransform

I am using opencv and c++. I have successfully obtained the transformation matrix between images A and B based on 3 common points in the images. Now I want to apply this found transformation matrix to the whole image. I was hoping that warpAffine could do the job but it gives me this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RNTK.jpg. However, I used only part of the affineTransform code where it finds the warped image because I already found the transformation matrix using another method. Can anybody tell if this is the correct way to transform the whole image if I already have a transformation marix?Here is the piece of that code http://pastebin.com/HFYSneG2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the transformation matrix, then cv::warpAffine is the right way to go. Your error message seems to be about the type of the transformation matrix and/or its size, which should be 2x3 float or double precision.

Comment: thanks. This is an extract of that part http://pastebin.com/HFYSneG2. As you can see the transformation matrix was initially defined as a 3x3 matrix and then it has been reshaped to a 2x3 matrix and it is a float. But it is not working

Comment: You are using reshape incorrectly - it is not designed to reduce the size of a matrix. You should use T.resize(2,3). BTW, you should post the code snippet here instead of linking to it.

Comment: I edited the question. Yes when I resize it to T.resize(2,3),it does not return any error but gives a weird image http://i.imgur.com/xNAIiDq.jpg

Comment: Try debugging this with synthetic images, for which you know what is the right transformation (affine), then see if you get the expected results

Comment: It should not be reshape nor resize. reshape will create matrix with too many values. resize will change the values of transformation itself, which also meaningless. Find what values of your 3x3 matrix are the relevant ones and copy them to 2x3 matrix.

Comment: @MichaelBurdinov , ordinarily, you're right, but in this case the last row is removed, and it should be OK, since it's just the affine row (0, 0, 1)

Comment: My transformation matrix is this http://i.imgur.com/Boh7EMY.jpg and I will need all the values to transform my left face image. Also,when I do T.resize(2,3) or T.reshape(2,3),it returns the same value as the picture and in the same order,no additional value

Comment: @Steph, are you sure that the values are correct? It is pretty unusual to match images of such different scales (more than 30 times larger from what I see).

Comment: I made a mistake as well,the order of the coordinates is not good.A transpose of the matrix is needed

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of the common points found on both images needed to be transposed and then warpAffine used